# Deleted BIOS boot options on laptop can't boot from anything

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios

I was messing around with BIOS, and I ended up accidently removing all options from the BIOS boot priority list including USB/CD option.

After a reboot it asked me which boot option I would like to use to boot up the laptop but it didn't give me any options whatsoever. When I went back into BIOS I saw that USB/CD option is still there, yet I'm unable to see any USB burners I plugged into any of the USB ports on the laptop.

My laptop is a Fujitsu Lifebook A series (AH531) with BIOS version 1.27. I have access to the boot options list on boot as well as BIOS. I tried resetting BIOS settings to default but it didn't fix the problem.

There is already a similar question on here but it hasn't been answered in 2 years.

EDIT: images.

First two are what i see when i turn the laptop (without pressing any buttons)
[image]

[image]

Then what the BIOS actually looks like:

[image]

Edit 2:
I've already tried resetting CMOS through taking out the battery. I was successful in resetting it, nonetheless the problem still remains.

Edit 3:
Advanced tab BIOS
[image]

Comment: did you plug the USB drive in before entering BIOS? Some BIOSes don't see drives if they were not present at boot - could this be a uEFI/CSM/Bios boot issue?

Comment: you tagged this as `windows-10` ... is there a windows 10 install you also can't get to?

Comment: I would go back into the bios and choose the option: Load Setup defaults.

Comment: The BIOS option for going back to the defaults might be called Reset.

Comment: to answer the questions. i did all sorts of options plugging usb in before bios plugging after. it never shows up anything on the list. idk much about uEFI/CSM/BIOS stuff much but apart from not working it looks ok lol.

Yes the entire problem started when my windows 10 suddenly stopped booting, so i tried installing a new system on it during restarting to boot from that i did the accidental thing i described in the question i assumed it was important info so i included it.

Comment: The defualt setup stuff in my BIOS is called LOAD SETUP DEFAULTS and is in the EXIT tab of the bios. It doesnt do anything to fix the probem.

I wasnt able to find anything called Reset.

Maybe important info: Top of the screen it says "Pheonix Securecore TIano Setup"

Comment: Could you kindly answer the following questions please. Does the laptop still contain a hard drive with a functional operating system or do you suspect the hard drive has died or windows has become corrupt? Have you tried replacing the hard drive with an old spare? Do you know if the USB devices you are plugging in are "bootable" USB's? Or are they just regular USB's with whatever data on them?

Comment: The laptop contains a hard drive with what i presume to be a corrupt version of windows. i Havent tried replacing the harddrive. I'll look into this. (not sure if i have any spare lying around that fit) The usb's im plugging in are both usb's that have been formatted by raspberry pi and rufus with an image of a linux ubuntu. Neither pop up on boot list.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is probably not a recoverable situation. Changes to UEFI NVRAM variables (like the boot entry list) can permanently brick your system.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the BIOS Advanced tab.

Comment: @harrymc advanced tab screenshot added.

Comment: @DanielB I see. I'll keep on trying. Maybe someone has a way. Thank you for the answer. so these NVRAM variables are unnaccecible?

Comment: No, absolutely not! As you discovered, you can easily edit them. However, because you can no longer boot anything, _you_ cannot access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All BIOS boot options were deleted and the BIOS shows no trace
of them and no interface for adding them back in.
Resetting the BIOS to default values is the only operation
left to you, but that also didn't help.

As the USB boot option is still there, another axis for attack
would have been to create a USB boot update for the BIOS
([link](http://www.badflash.com/bad-flash/)).
However, even this avenue is impossible, since
[Fujitsu Support](https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/IndexQuickSearchResult.asp?lng=COM&Q=Fujitsu%20lifebook%20AH531/GFO&OpenTab=)
does not furnish a naked BIOS version, but only an update program
that needs to be run in Windows.

You might be able to create a Windows To Go USB, which is
basically a portable Windows version, and use in it the
Fujitsu BIOS update program. Some tools for that are
[Hasleo WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html)
or
[EaseUS OS2Go](https://www.easeus.com/system-to-go/windows-to-go-alternative.html).

If the above doesn't help in solving the problem,
only Fujitsu Support or a qualified repairman could fix this problem.
But as the Fujitsu Lifebook A series (AH531) dates from 2011,
the chances for you to have it done are very low, and even if
possible the price would be too high for such an old computer.

I apologize for my negative opinion, but if none of my above
suggestions can solve the problem, then I don't think that
fixing the problem is within your means, and then the price
of getting it fixed by a professional (if at all possible)
is really better spent on a new computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the BIOS Settings by removing the CMOS battery for 60 seconds and then re-installing it. This should return any BIOS settings changes back to normal:

[image]

Source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zp6S1-7YzHg

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've already tried this from the exact same video. i even left it out for 5 mins without battery, cable or cmos battery. still the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: Boot options are stored in NVRAM. As the name suggests, it is not volatile.

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS in your picture looks like the one from Insyde that I have on my computer.

I lost all boot options when I upgraded my computer BIOS. Back then, I managed to restore the boot option that I needed by enabling secure boot and selecting a file as trusted.

Here is how I [did it for a Debian installation](https://superuser.com/a/1586250/1203531):

> Updating the BIOS resets it to defaults. It seems that, as a side effect, it forgets what file to trust as a boot option on the existing installation. To direct it to the correct file to boot, you will need to choose "Select an UEFI file as trusted", navigate to EFI > debian > shimx64.efi, choose any name for it, and confirm. This option is greyed out until you set up password. You can clear the password after saving the option.

There should be a differently named file for your Windows installation if there is still one on the disk.

This is a workaround. There should be another more "advanced" factory mode that allows modifying more boot options, but it is typically hidden and not supposed to be used by an end user.

I don't know what's wrong with the USB not being detected, considering that you already have the legathy USB mode enabled, but it did happen to me in the past too if it is of any comfort.